# вывести дату в UTC (Yii2, Gridwiew format DateTime)

Tags: php, yii2, datetime, gridview

Мне нужно чтоб выодилась дата в формате "0000-00-00 00:00:00 UTC";
И все отлично, но выводится вместо "GMT" вместо "UTC", вод код:

В Yii2 в Gridwiew:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'start_date',
    'format'    => ['DateTime', 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s T'],
],
```

Пробовал:

`'format'    => ['DateTime', 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s UTC'],` → выводит "GMT"
`'format'    => ['DateTime', 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s \U\T\C'],` → выводит "UT\"
`'format'    => ['DateTime', 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s \U\TC'],` → выводит "UT"
`'format'    => ['DateTime', 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s UT\C'],` → выводит "GMT\"

Кто знает как преобразовать может на этапе выбора из mysql,
либо как экранировать это UTC, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так:

```
'format' => ['DateTime', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss \'UTC']
```